# Snowflake ODBC driver returns all fields as text in MSAccess passthrough queries

Tags: ms-access, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc

I have set up an MSAccess as a UI for users to read and write data in Snowflake. I use the Snowflake provided ODBC driver (snowflake64_odbc-2.25.10) and have passthrough queries in MSAccess to feed data from Snowflake. However all NUMBER fields in Snowflake appear in Access as text, which means I cannot format them (percentages, currencies, etc). Even if I convert the field to number in the passthrough select statement, it still appears as text.

Thanks to anyone that can help me with retrieving the field type properly.

Comment: Please share your version of Access, and ODBC connection string you're using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, please see below: ODBC;driver={SnowflakeDSIIDriver};AUTHENTICATOR = externalbrowser;server=XXXX.snowflakecomputing.com;database=XXX;schema=XXX;warehouse=XXX; uid=XXX

Comment: I'm using Access 2016 (Access 2007 - 2016 file format)